# Windows 10 crashes after sleep intermittently

Tags: windows-10, sleep

Just upgraded to Windows 10 on my home-built 3 year old desktop PC from Windows 8.1. After the upgrade I reset the PC so that I got rid of all the cruft from the previous installation.

I have reinstalled all my apps and restored my data, but when the PC goes to sleep, on waking it is like the reset button has been pressed and goes to the BIOS screen and reboots. This doesn't happen every time, only intermittently. Any tips on how to troubleshoot and find the cause?

I have installed all the latest updates and drivers.

Comment: You have installed the chipset drivers?  Most power state problems like this are driver related.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. When I installed Windows 10 I just let Windows install the drivers, I didn't install any specifically. In device manager everything looked good (no yellow exclamation marks). My motherboard is GA-Z68MA-D2H-B3 and the gigabyte website only has WIndows 8.1 drivers. I've installed those and we'll see how it goes.

Comment: After installing the WIndows 8.1 drivers I am still seeing the same issue. I guess my motherboard is just not compatible with WIndows 10. Any ideas before I consider going back?

Answer (score 0):

Try going into the power option page and 'choose what the power buttons do' and be sure not to choose hibernate on any of the options.
 You may find it useful to turn all options off and only choose sleep for the 'when you close the lid' option.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)